# .htaccess url "return url back to original url"

Tags: .htaccess

I'm a new to this site and I was wondering how do I have my url stay the same for example I have a url:

```
http://www.somesite.com/1234/a-b-c
```

And when some one adds extra info to the end of the url `/a-b-c` for example:

```
http://www.somesite.com/1234/a-sss-vadv-b-c
```

The url will return back to its origianl url when the web page is loaded into the browser for example.

```
http://www.somesite.com/1234/a-b-c
```

Does any know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  A bit more information is required to provided a good answer.  Do you already have rewrite rules in place as this can impact how this is handled.  Does the /a-b-c page actually exist or should it be a 404 not found?

Answer (score 0):

In yout httpd.conf make this entry

```
 ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mysite.com
```